# What library is used to integrate with Android TV Remote service?

Tags: android, protocols, android-tv, television

I've seen lately that apps other than [Google's Official Android TV remote app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.tv.remote), such as ["Remote Android TV"](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=fr.bouyguestelecom.remote) and ["CetusPlay"](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.cetusplay.remotephone) succeeded in connecting to Android TV's  built-in protocol of remote control and serve as an alternative that works seamlessly.

I was wondering what kind of library/protocol they've been using and how can I integrate it into my app, so I could use it for my next ATV project. I tried to decompile these apps but couldn't get anything to run.

Could you help me with it?

Comment: Have you seen: https://developer.android.com/training/tv/start/controllers

Comment: @morrison-chang It seems like it's ATV apps handling remote events rather than being a way to develop a remote app and invoke events on TV.